# How to make certain content of the post noindex and no follow. not entire post?

Tags: post-meta, seo, plugins, noindex

in my woocomemrce website i am trying to embade faqs which are generated using a short cut code . these faqs are common for all products which may lead to serious duplicate content issue  . how to make only the faqs content to noindex and make the remaining part of the product like description and photos under follow and index ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some spiders honor the `<noindex>...</noindex>` tags within a page so in that case you could simply wrap your FAQ content with `<noindex></noindex>`. But I honestly don't know if Google or for that matter which spiders honor the tag.

Since this is not really a WordPress question it's off topic for this forum. You'd more than likely have better luck with posting this to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: but the main problem you cant add the meta tags inside the post in the word press , you can add it to the entire post but i am wondering how to do it inside the post content .

Comment: Are you adding the shortcode in code or via the post edit screen? If you're using the edit screen simply switch to HTML mode and wrap your shortcode in like this {<noindex>[shortcode]</noindex>}.

Comment: thanks for the information and all major search engines honor no follow and noindex just for information .Thanks for your time

Comment: Ignore the {} in my comment above. Formatting error on my part, use <noindex>[shortcode]</noindex>. Did this answer you question?

Comment: i think so i need to give it a try and make sure it works

Comment: i guess i frames are the only solution